# How to get backbone and HTML5 elements to work in IE8

Tags: html, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

I have a very light backbone app which I've been developing recently and I'm having a lot of trouble getting HTML5 elements to work in IE8. I've found multiple blog posts around the place talking about html5shiv and modernizer

I have tried both of these as CDNs and local JS libraries but no matter what IE will not detect the new elements.

I found an [old issue on github](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1378) that is the same as mine but details that html5shiv should fix my issue but it really doesn't. I've double checked that the JS libraries are loaded and run, I've tried moving it around above my stylesheets, below my stylesheets, and at the very top of the head section but nothing will work. I even found an [old blog post](http://css-tricks.com/html5-innershiv/) which talks about work arounds for my exact issue, and says that the new html5shiv as of Jan 2013 should fix it. I'm really at a loss here, has anyone had this working nicely?

I'm running backbone 0.9.10 and jQuery 1.8.2 with a Drupal 7 backend but I think these are irrelevant.

Comment: How about posting your relevant code so we can take a look?

Comment: @Colin not sure what code I could post that would help, this looks like it might be an issue with jQuery (be it very old) http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6485

Comment: Can you come up with a simplified test case that demonstrates the issue? Without being reproducible, I'm afraid we'd just be guessing.

Comment: @Colin Apologies, yes I understand that, I actually went to do this with jsfiddle and couldn't reproduce it myself. On The jquery bug above there is this comment http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6485#comment:57 which describes my issue and the same in the most recent comment, but in the JS Bin example he links to the bug doesn't actually exist. I was left at a loss here and haven't tried to tackle the issue since, will try more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acbramley/DnAZq/9/) which demonstrates my issue and shows that html5shiv should indeed fix the problem. It also shows it has nothing to do with backbone, this is a bug in jquery.

The broken dom elements come from the line

```
$(document.body).append($('.test').clone());
```

Viewing the full result page in IE8 correctly shows  tags. Removing [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) reproduces the issue I have, even though adding html5shiv to my own project does not fix the issue.